# Android: How to enable device administraton?

Tags: android, admin, device

I'd like to turn off the screen by my application but I can't get device admin.

This is my code:

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
ComponentName mDeviceAdminSample;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN = 1;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mContext=this;


    mDeviceAdminSample = new ComponentName(this, Act_01_LockScreen.class);
    mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);




}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    Boolean mAdminActive = isActiveAdmin();



    if (!mAdminActive) {

            // Launch the activity to have the user enable our admin.
            Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminSample);
            intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                    mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ENABLE_ADMIN);
            // return false - don't update checkbox until we're really active

    }else{
        mDPM.lockNow();
    }





}

private boolean isActiveAdmin() {
    return mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdminSample);
}
```

}

This code doesn't show me anything. How I can do?

Many thanks...

Please don't show me any link that haven't the soltuion...

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you might try this trick, based on changing brightness level.

```
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams windowParams = window.getAttributes();
windowParams.screenBrightness = 0;
window.setAttributes(windowParams);
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but this doesn't answer to my question and If I used this code I'm not able to exit from standby anymore.